# Xamarin iOS black screen

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, uistoryboard

I´m very new to Xamarin and currently I want to develop a little iOS app that receives data from a REST-Service.
So I have the following Storyboard:
[image: Storyboard]

In the table view there should be some entries that are consumed from the REST-Service. When you click on one row you should be "redirected" to a detail view which should be the right View.

The problem is, that the screen of the right story board is just black:
[image: Blackscreen]

Well let´s have a look at my code, first the FinishedLaunching method in my AppDelegate.cs:

```
public override void FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application)
    {
        Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        UIStoryboard storyboard;
        UIViewController initialViewController;

        var credential = CredentialController.Instance.FindAccount(CustomStaticLiterals.AppName);
        if (credential == null)
        {
            storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("AccountCreationViewController", NSBundle.MainBundle);
            initialViewController = storyboard.InstantiateInitialViewController() as UIViewController;
        }
        else
        {
            storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("OverviewViewController", NSBundle.MainBundle);
            initialViewController = storyboard.InstantiateInitialViewController() as UIViewController;
        }

        Window.RootViewController = initialViewController;
        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
    }
```

Here is my ProjectOverviewController:

```
public partial class ProjectOverviewController : UITableViewController
{
    public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    private static readonly NSString callHistoryCellId = new NSString("ProjectCell");

    public ProjectOverviewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        TableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse(typeof(UITableViewCell), callHistoryCellId);
        ProjectOverviewDataSource source = new ProjectOverviewDataSource(this);
        source.DetailProjectEvent += DetailProjectPage;
        TableView.Source = source;
        Projects = new List<Project>();
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        var credentials = CredentialController.Instance.FindAccount(CustomStaticLiterals.AppName);
        var service = new ServiceInvoker();
        Projects = new List<Project>(service.GetCurrentProjectsOfUserAsync(credentials.UserName).Result);
    }

    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

    }

    void DetailProjectPage(object sender, EventArgs e, int index)
    {
        var currentProject = Projects[index];
        var projectViewController =
            Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ProjectViewController") as ProjectViewController;

        if (projectViewController != null)
        {

            projectViewController.Initialize(currentProject);
            NavigationController.PushViewController(projectViewController, true);
        }
    }

    class ProjectOverviewDataSource : UITableViewSource
    {
        ProjectOverviewController controller;
        public delegate void DetailProjectHandler(object sender, EventArgs e, int index);
        public event DetailProjectHandler DetailProjectEvent;

        public ProjectOverviewDataSource(ProjectOverviewController controller)
        {
            this.controller = controller;
        }

        // Returns the number of rows in each section of the table
        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {
            return controller.Projects.Count;
        }
        //
        // Returns a table cell for the row indicated by row property of the NSIndexPath
        // This method is called multiple times to populate each row of the table.
        // The method automatically uses cells that have scrolled off the screen or creates new ones as necessary.
        //
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(ProjectOverviewController.callHistoryCellId);

            int row = indexPath.Row;
            cell.TextLabel.Text = controller.Projects[row].Header;

            return cell;
        }

        public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var index = indexPath.Row;
            if (DetailProjectEvent != null)
            {
                DetailProjectEvent(this, new EventArgs(), index);
            }
            tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the the ProjectViewController:

```
public sealed partial class ProjectViewController : UIPageViewController
{
    private Project masterModel;
    public ProjectViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public void Initialize(Project masterModel)
    {
        if (masterModel == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(masterModel));
        }

        this.masterModel = masterModel;


    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        Title = masterModel.Header;
        CustomerField = new UITextField();
        CustomerField.Text = masterModel.Customer;
        ObjectAddressField = new UITextField();
        ObjectAddressField.Text = masterModel.Customer;
    }
}
```

Well there is an other strange behaviour I realized:
When I wanted to set a text for the CustomerField.Text and ObjectAddress.Text property I got a NullReferenceException that the two objects CustomerField and ObjectAddressField are null which leads me to the conclusion that there must a wrong initialization of the ProjectViewController.

If you have some other recommendations about my code, feel free to tell my, because as I said I´m a rookie with Xamarin and App-Development.